# How to display all the properties of the selected reviewers?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Consider the business process *"Review and Approve (one or more reviewers) - Assign a review task to multiple reviewers"*.

When I [choose](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/common/picker.inc.ftl) reviewers I see only their properties `cm:userName`. How to display all the properties of the type [`cm:person`](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml#L168)?

For example:

```
cm:userName
cm:firstName
cm:middleName
cm:email
cm:organizationId
cm:jobtitle
cm:googleusername
```

And so on...

Instead of this container (part of the [association.ftl](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/association.ftl)):

```
...
<div id="${controlId}-currentValueDisplay" class="current-values"></div> 
...
```

I would like to use table. IMHO for that I should override some parts of the 
[Alfresco.ObjectFinder](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/webapp/components/object-finder/object-finder.js), such as:

```
if (this.options.displayMode == "items")
{
   Dom.get(this.id + "-currentValueDisplay").innerHTML = displayValue;
}
```

...etc. But how to display **all the properties** of the selected reviewers?

Let's say, this part:

```
displayValue += 
    this.options.objectRenderer.renderItem(
        item, 
        16, 
        "<div class='itemtype-" + $html(item.type) + 
        "' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>{icon} {name}</div>"
    );
```

I assume that it's property is `name`

Ok, then where to find the mapping `"property in object-finder : property in the person type"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the companyname, email etc fields to you need to modify the following files in the repo side.

```
C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\repository\forms\pickerresults.lib.js

C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\repository\forms\pickerresults.lib.ftl
```

In the pickerresults.lib.js, I added the required extra properties in the CreatePersonResult(node) method.

```
function createPersonResult(node)
{
   var personObject = 
   {
      typeShort: node.typeShort,
      isContainer: false,
      properties: {},
      displayPath: node.displayPath,
      nodeRef: "" + node.nodeRef
   }

   // define properties for person
   personObject.properties.userName = node.properties.userName;
   personObject.properties.name = (node.properties.firstName ? node.properties.firstName + " " : "") + 
      (node.properties.lastName ? node.properties.lastName : "") +
         " (" + node.properties.userName + ")";
   personObject.properties.jobtitle = (node.properties.jobtitle ? node.properties.jobtitle  : "");
   //Add the extra properties here
   personObject.properties.organization =(node.properties.organization ? node.properties.organization  : "");
   personObject.properties.googleusername =(node.properties.googleusername ? node.properties.googleusername  : "");   

   return personObject;
}
```

In the pickerresults.lib.ftl, I added the extra properties to the result set, below to the `"selectable" : ${row.selectable?string}</#if>`

```
"nodeRef": "${row.item.nodeRef}"<#if row.selectable?exists>,
"selectable" : ${row.selectable?string}</#if>,
"company": "${row.item.properties.organization!""}",
"googleusername": "${row.item.properties.googleusername!""}",
"jobtitle": "${row.item.properties.jobtitle!""}"
```

[image]

Hope this helps you now.

Comment: I'm using Enterprise version (5.0.x). You should be able to find out the source files from alfresco-remote-api-5.X.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Object-finder.js is used for different kind of objects like person, tags etc.

`item.type` is `cm:person`, but it doesn't have all the person of person object here. Refer the below image.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give me the webscript url? I will check quickly and let you k now the possiblities.