# How to get a list of assignments and display it in the workflow form?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Alfresco Community v5.2 includes some of preconfigured workflows that available on the page `/share/page/start-workflow`

Among others, there is one that is interested for me - is *"Review and Approve (one or more reviewers) - Assign a review task to multiple reviewers"*. This business process is well suited to the requirements of one of our customers. I copied it and customize accordingly.

Now, for each user's task there is a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711810/how-to-add-custom-table-to-the-reviewtask-screen-of-workflow-form) (while empty).

When I start the workflow, I can assign executors and also some [additional properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557788/how-to-display-all-the-properties-of-the-selected-reviewers) is available.

I would like to display all the executors names in this table. What kind of API is available for me in this case?

Where are stored selected executors and how to get a list of them by using JavaScript?

Comment: you have to create a form field in workflow and custom ftl file which will render your table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a form field

'" field id="mswf:prop" set="details" label="details"  read-only="true"  '"

"control template="org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/custom.ftl"
"

Define one more property which will show your table
  Define a custom ftl as form field. And call a repo webscript and get response of  your repo webscript which will return your executors list and you can render it in table in your ftl file